# Can't add user to firestore database after signing up with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a user to a firestore database after signing up through firebase with email and password. I get no errors, and the user is created and is visible in firebase auth. However the user is not added to the firestore database.

Does anyone know how to make this work? My code snippet is pasted below.

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();

auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(cred => {
  const userId = cred.user.uid;
  const userData = {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email
  };
  db.collection("users").doc(userId).set(userData).then(() => {
    console.log("User successfully added to the DB!");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("Error adding user to the DB: ", e);
  });
}).then(() => {
  console.log('User created! - ' + email);
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(e.message);
  txtErrMsg.classList.remove('hide');
  txtErrMsg.innerHTML = e.message;
});
```

FYI: I have console logged the parameters (userId and userData), and they appear just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong with my code.

I wrote another method `auth.onAuthStateChanged()` which was interfering with my action to write to the database. Since I have two auth files (`signup.js` and `login.js`), I decided to only keep this method in `login.js` and to remove it from `signup.js`.

Now I can successfully add the user to the DB upon signup (`signup.js`), and I don't need to add anything to the DB when a user is simply logging in (`login.js`).

I hope this helps anyone out there experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I just updated my answer - before I saw that you had figured it out yourself. Time well spent on my part. Haha. Glad you figured it out, though!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced that problem myself. The only way I managed to get this working was to await auth first, and then add the user to firestore:

I have a `firebaseConfig.js` where I set up the usersCollection:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = { 
  apiKey: ......
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();

const usersCollection = db.collection('users');

export { auth, usersCollection };
```

Then, I use it like this.

```
const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js');

....

const cred = await fb.auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        'someemail@test.com',
        'password123'
    )
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e.message);
    });

if (cred) {
    console.log({ cred });
    const userId = cred.user.uid;
    const userData = {
        firstName: 'firstName',
        lastName: 'lastName',
        email: 'email',
    };

    fb.usersCollection
      .doc(userId)
      .set(userData)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('User successfully added to the DB!');
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('User created!);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('Error adding user to the DB: ', e);
      });
}
```

When I ran this code I got the following in my log:
[image: from the firefox log]

And it appears in my database like this:
[image: database entry]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Magnus. I tried doing it this way but I still run into the same problem... None of the `console.log`'s from the `set` function are printed to the console. Do you know why that is?